# Cannot invoke "" because "" is null mockito /junit

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

as per title I am facing an issue when testing a service method.I suppose it should be some config problem or much more some wrong usage of mockito.

There is the code of the CustomerDataService

```
@Service
 public class CustomerDataService {

@Autowired
CustomerDataRepository customerDataRepository;

...

@Transactional
public void methodTotest(boolean consent, Long dialogId) {
    CustomerData customer = customerDataRepository.findCustomerByDialogId(dialogId);

    if (!consent) {
        
    customerDataRepository.deleteById(customer.getCustomerId());
    }else{
        customer.setConsentGiven(true);
        customerDataRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

In the test CustomerDataServiceTest
@SpringBootTest
class CustomerDataServiceTest {

```
@Autowired
CustomerDataService customerDataService;

@MockBean
CustomerDataRepository customerDataRepository;

@Test
void removeCustomerDataWhenConsentIsNotGiven() {
    CustomerData customerDataTest = customerData;
    //when
    customerDataService.giveConsent(false,22L);
   

    //then
    
    
verify(customerDataRepository,times(1)).save(customerDataTest);
     }
```

The error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mypackage.CustomerData.getCustomerId()" because "customer" is null
```

this is the second line of the myMethod
Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing how and what beans you mocked there's no way of telling what's the problem here. Also, in your test there are no calls to `methodTotest()`.

Comment: Can you please show your entire TestClass?

Comment: I am testing the service layer so I used @MockBean to mock it inside this class plus autowiring the repo(as I do in the normal service). The repository methods are simply from the CustomerDataReppository that implements JPA repository

Comment: @GJohannes I updated the question with more info about the test class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple. You mocked a class `customerDataRepository` but did not instruct it the mock what to do if the corresponding method is called. Mockito mocks then default back on `doing nothing` by method call and if there is a return value `return null`.
Since your returned customerData is null you get your NPE when calling on this object. In your case this is in the error case that you get by calling `getCustomerId()`.

To solve this issue simply instruct your mock

```
@Test
void removeCustomerDataWhenConsentIsNotGiven() {
   CustomerData customerDataTest = customerData;
   //when
   Mockito.when(customerDataRepository.findCustomerByDialogId(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new CustomerData()); // <-- Add this line
   customerDataService.giveConsent(false,22L);
   //then 
   verify(customerDataRepository,times(1)).save(customerDataTest);
}
```

you can obviously replace `Mockito.any()` with `Mockito.anyInt()` or `42` and `new CustomerData()` with a object you previously created. I think you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have just corrected method names before posting it to Stackoverflow, and method you are calling in the test: `giveConsent` is, actually, the same method as `methodTotest` of the CustomerDataService.

Before calling `customerDataService.giveConsent(false,22L);`, you need to configure you repository to return some test (not null! or mocked) customerData entity:

```
when(customerDataRepository.findCustomerByDialogId(22L)).thenReturn(customerDataTest);
customerDataService.giveConsent(false,22L);
```

**Note**: since you are passing `false` as 1st variable, you will get to this branch of code

```
    if (!consent) {  
      customerDataRepository.deleteById(customer.getCustomerId());
    }
```

And in the test you are expecting `save()` method to be called, so the test will fail.