# InitializationError on running unit tests in intelliJ idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, mockito, junit4

When I am trying to run a unit test from any extension in my SAP hybris project, I am getting an initialization error in the IDE which is not letting the test cases to execute.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.3\jbr\bin\java.exe" -ea -Dplatformhome=C:/Heineken_2205_NEW/Hybris_2205_7/hybris/bin/platform -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=65062:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\rishab.sud\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file810978677 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.heinekenint.etrade.b2b.core.commerceservices.order.hook.impl.EtradeCommerceRedisCartCalculationMethodHookTest
```

---

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:19)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.loadImplementations(ClassPathLoader.java:145)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPluginImplementation(ClassPathLoader.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.findPlatformMockMaker(ClassPathLoader.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.<clinit>(ClassPathLoader.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<init>(MockitoCore.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsMocks.<init>(ReturnsMocks.java:18)
    at org.mockito.Answers.<clinit>(Answers.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3837)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3859)
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumValue(AnnotationParser.java:479)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:344)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:717)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:262)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1211)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1197)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:549)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.getAnnotations(FrameworkField.java:45)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.addToAnnotationLists(TestClass.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.mockito.plugins.StackTraceCleanerProvider.getStackTraceCleaner(org.mockito.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceCleaner)" because the return value of "org.mockito.internal.configuration.ClassPathLoader.getStackTraceCleanerProvider()" is null
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 48 more
```

Process finished with exit code -1

I want my test cases to run.

Details: **IntelliJ version is 2022.3.3, Junit version is 4**

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153070/cannot-invoke-because-is-null-mockito-junit
also, check https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/issues/255